# aws s3 cli - how to get list of prefixes in a folder in desc order

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have a folder in s3

```
s3://main_bucket/fold1/
```

there are a lot of folders in `fold1`

```
s3://main_bucket/fold1/fold001/..
s3://main_bucket/fold1/fold002/..
s3://main_bucket/fold1/fold003/..
```

Now I want to get the list of all prefixes inside fold1

i.e

```
fold003
fold002
fold001
```

in descending order.

How can I do this using AWS CLI?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `s3api` command `list-objects-v2` that returns fields as JSON:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket BUCKET-NAME --prefix fold1/ --delimiter '/' --query 'reverse(CommonPrefixes[].[Prefix])' --output text

fold1/fold003/
fold1/fold002/
fold1/fold001/
```

Specifying the `delimiter` as a slash (`/`) causes the results to include a list of `CommonPrefixes`, which are effectively folder names. The `reverse()` operation returns the results in reverse order and `--output text` removes the JSON formatting.

Then, to extract just the name of the folder, you can use `cut` like this:

```
aws s3api list-objects-v2 --bucket BUCKET-NAME --prefix fold1/ --delimiter '/' --query 'reverse(CommonPrefixes[].[Prefix])' --output text | cut -d'/' -f2

fold003
fold002
fold001
```

This works on my Mac. If you are using Windows, then you might need to play with the quotation marks.